# Storing and retrieving images from/to database using HTML and Angular JS

Tags: javascript, html, sql, database, asp.net-web-api

I am building a Single Page Application using Web API, HTML and Angular JS to implement CRUD operations on a list of employees.

I have created a new database in Visual Studio with a table named Employee consisting of the following attributes together with their data types:

- ID (int)
- FullName (nvarchar(50))
- JobPosition (nvarchar(50))
- Motto (nvarchar(100))
- Hobbies (nvarchar(100))
- Hometown (nvarchar(50))
- PersonalBlog (nvarchar(50))
- Image (varbinary(MAX))

According to my research, the best way to store images in a database is by using the varbinary(max) type.  However, I cannot figure out how can I implement the following functionalities in my project:

1. Storing manually images (Since the database will be populated by a number of 
   records before)
2. Retrieve those images (possibly using Angular JS) and display them on an 
   HTML page
3. Storing those images from an HTML Form

Answer (score 0):

I will explain 1 of the available choice to get this done.

- Step 1 : Convert the image to base64 / string
- Step 2 : Bind it to Image
- Step 3 : Post the Employee object to WebApi
- Step 4 : Convert the base64 string in Image to bytes

byte[] imageInBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(employyeView.Image);

- Step 5 : Assign values to entity variable, for Image field assign
  imageInBytes.
- Step 6 : Insert to db

Or if you can convert image to binary in Angular then you can skip step 4 and 5.

For converting image to base64 you can use  https://github.com/ninjatronic/angular-base64.

Please follow the instructions for using this library, you can simply call:

```
var imageBase64=$base64.encode(image);
```